# How to position the SharePoint top navigation to center?

Tags: navigation, office365, master-pages, sharepoint-online

For one of the Projects I am working on, I have a master page added to the portal. Basically the created master page is a copy of seattle master page and renamed it with something else as the client in future might ask to add footer, header etc so that can be easily done in the created master page rather than touching the default seattle master page. Currently the created master page doesn't have any customization added.

So as per the first requirement now they want to center the top navigation bar, is there an easy fix for this? simply by changing the alignment, may be for the container that holds the top nav bar? I have referred to many links on this issue and haven't been able to get any of those to work. I am working on Office 365, so if anyone knows how to approach this, the help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple to center the navigation. 
Adding the following short snippet of css.

```
.ms-breadcrumb-top {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you have Publishing Features Enabled, you can simply set the Alternate CSS using "Site Settings" --> "Master page" --> Expand "Alternate CSS URL".

If not, you can set the alternate CSS using code. E.g. through JSOM (but also PowerShell or CSOM) using the following:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();

web.set_alternateCssUrl('/Style%20Library/custom.css');

web.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    alert("Alternate CSS Successfully Set");
}

function onQueryFailed(error){
    console.log(error)
}
```

In this case the CSS file with the snippet above is saved as "custom.css" in the "Style Library".